# How can i take values from csv file and print the values that are within + or - 1 of the value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, graph

I am quite new to python so please bear with me.

I am trying to pick one of the values printed, find it in the csv file, and print the values + or - 1 around it.

Here is the code to pick the values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv", skiprows=[1])
magnitudes = df['Magnitude '].values
times = df['Time '].values
zscores = np.abs(stats.zscore(magnitudes, ddof=1))
outlier_indicies = np.argwhere(zscores > 3).flatten()
numbers = print(times[outlier_indicies])
```

The values printed are below.

```
 2455338.895 2455350.644 2455391.557 2455404.776 2455413.734 2455451.661
 2455473.49  2455477.521 2455507.505 2455702.662 2455734.597 2455765.765
 2455776.575 2455826.593 2455842.512 2455866.508 2455996.796 2456017.767
 2456047.694 2456058.732 2456062.722 2456071.924 2456082.802 2456116.494
 2456116.535 2456116.576 2456116.624 2456116.673 2456116.714 2456116.799
 2456123.527 2456164.507 2456166.634 2456391.703 2456455.535 2456455.6
 2456501.763 2456511.616 2456519.731 2456525.49  2456547.588 2456570.526
 2456595.515 2456776.661 2456853.543 2456920.511 2456953.496 2457234.643
 2457250.68  2457252.672 2457278.526 2457451.89  2457485.722 2457497.93
 2457500.674 2457566.874 2457567.877 2457644.495 2457661.553 2457675.513
```

An example of the csv file is below.

```
      Time        Magnitude   Magnitude error 
  2455260.853      19.472             0.150
  2455260.900      19.445             0.126
  2455261.792      19.484             0.168
  2455262.830      19.157             0.261
  2455264.814      19.376             0.150
...           ...         ...               ...
  2457686.478      19.063             0.176
  2457689.480      19.178             0.128
  2457690.475      19.386             0.171
  2457690.480      19.092             0.112
  2457691.476      19.191             0.122
```

For example, I want to pick the first value, which is `2455338.895` i would like to print all the values + or - 1 of it (in the time column) (and later graph it).

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for (assuming you want single number query which you mentioned in question that way):

```
numbers = times[outlier_indicies]
print(df[(df['Time']<numbers[0]+1) & (df['Time']>numbers[0]-1)]['Time'])
```

Looping over `numbers` to get all intervals are straightforward, if that is what you might be interested in.

***EDIT***:
The for loop looks like this:

```
print(pd.concat([df[(df['Time']<i+1) & (df['Time']>i-1)]['Time'] for i in numbers]))
```

The non-loop version if there are no overlapping intervals in `(numbers[i]-1,numbers[i]+1)`:

```
intervals = pd.DataFrame(data={'start': numbers-1,'finish': numbers+1})
starts = pd.DataFrame(data={'start': 1}, index=intervals.start.tolist())
finishs = pd.DataFrame(data={'finish': -1},index=intervals.finish.tolist())
transitions = pd.merge(starts, finishs, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True).fillna(0)
transitions['transition'] = (transitions.pop('finish')+transitions.pop('start')).cumsum()
B = pd.DataFrame(index=numbers)
pd.merge(transitions, B, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True).fillna(method='ffill').loc[B.index].astype(bool)
print(transitions[transitions.transition == 1].index)
```

In case of overlapping you can merge consecutive overlapping intervals in `intervals` dataframe with the help of following column and then run the above code(needs maybe a couple more lines to complete):

```
intervals['overlapping'] = (intervals.finish - intervals.start.shift(-1))>0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Apologies for the confusion, I am looking for all the numbers + or - around the value as I believe that they are needed to graph. How would you print/graph all the values? Thanks

Comment: @AaronHuang How large is your data?

Comment: It is quite large, 6000 rows, I am happy to share the file.

Comment: If looping doesn't work, the solution needs to be different. I will edit it to solve without loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the numbers:

```
all_nums = numbers.split(" ")
first = all_nums[0]
threshold = 1
result = []
for num in all_nums:
    if abs(float(first) - float(num)) < threshold:
        result.append(num) # float(num) if you want number instead of str

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I try the code, I get the error  
' AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split' '